# unix - Find file in directory x but exclude directory y

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file system

```
/x/./
```

directory `x` contains directories `a`, `b`, `c`, `y`.
I want to find everything `/x/./` but not in `/x/y/./`
How should I write?

I tried

```
find /x/./ -path "/x/y/" -prune -type f
```

but it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` is very literal.  It does not consider `/x/y/` to be below `/x/./`, because it's not `/x/./y/`, even though those two paths refer to the same directory.  You *may* also have a problem with the way it combines operations when no explicit logical connective is given, I can never remember the way that works (it's easier to just use explicit connectives all the time).

When `.` is not the entire pathname all by itself, it is always safe to leave it out, and in this context, the trailing slashes are also unnecessary. Try instead

```
find "/x" -path "/x/y" -prune -o -type f -print
```

The double quotes are technically also unnecessary in this case, but if the pathnames contained any special characters they would be necessary.

**EDIT:**  If you know the files you're looking for are two levels down, you tell `find` to search starting two levels down. There are two possibilities: you know the name of the subdirectory that contains all the files you want --

```
# by definition nothing in /x/a/foo can be under /x/y
find "/x/a/foo" -type f -print
```

-- or you don't --

```
# The stars in the first argument have to be outside the quotes,
# so the shell expands them.  The stars in the -path argument have to
# be inside quotes so the shell *doesn't* expand them.
find "/x/"*/* -path "/x/y/*" -prune -o -type f -print
```

The logical connectives are hard to explain.  `-path whatever` and `-type f` act like `if` conditions, whereas `-prune` and `-print` act like the stuff inside the conditional block, and `-o` in this context is acting more like `else` than `or`; but that's an oversimplification, and the details matter.  Please read the *entire* [GNU find manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/index.html).  If you are still unsure about something after you do that, please ask a new question here.

Comment: what if the files I'm looking for is somewhere layers down x, eg. I know I should go two more layers, should I use /x/././ to refer to it or any other method?

Comment: On the other hand, when should there be logic connection? why not before -path or before -print?

Comment: why use -o not -a here? the logical seem to me "find all but in this path or find all type = f"

Answer (score 1):

```
find  /x -type d -path /x/y -prune -o -type f -print
```

This will exclude the y directory.

Comment: `-name '*'` is not the same thing as `-type f`, and if `-name '*'` is really the behavior you want, just leave it out altogether (`find ... -prune -o -print`).

Comment: change -name '*' to -type f will do